# Should one flag questions already on hold?

Tags: discussion, flags

Is it ever beneficial to flag questions that are already on hold?

So yesterday I saw a post that was blatant spam with the contents of the question something along the lines of...

`"Get hot girls numbers NOW!, click this link... (blah, blah, blah)".`

I did not flag it as it was on hold. But, should I have flagged it to bring it the attention of moderators quicker or does flagging a question already on hold make no difference?

Comment: I clicked on that link and now I have 8 girlfriends.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you see "blatant spam" then flag it as spam, even if it is on hold. Putting spam on hold is of little use so you are actually taking care of the *real* problem if you flag it as spam.

When a post is really blatant spam, it boggles the mind why would anybody decide that putting on hold would be the right thing to do.

Other than spam, if there is any issue with the post that just closing it does not fix, and that you can't fix, then you should raise an appropriate flag.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to close a question then it is to get it deleted. I the case of something as blatant as this, I would recommend downvoting, voting to close, *and* flagging as spam. But yes, at a minimum it should definitely be flagged as spam.

Comment: 6 spam flags will delete a post automatically, and people with as low as 15 rep can flag. So there's a much greater pool of people who can flag than people who can close.

Answer (score 5):

If it was put on hold and then edited to add the spam, then someone should spot it in the re-open queue and take appropriate action.
Although don't rely on that.

If the question was put on hold and should have been marked spam, then I would suggest flagging it for sure.

However, if you see a question which is hard-spam as you have described here, ie if it links to a potentially virus site (etc), then I would flag for moderator attention. 
As the question is currently on-hold it might not receive much additional attention from natural traffic, and therefore not be quickly closed through the (usually fast) standard spam flag.

But it's up to you to decide based on the severity of the spam, where it links to, profanities, etc

Comment: Hmm... interesting scenario you've got there... someone editing a post to *add* spam. I've never seen that happen. Is it a thing?

Comment: @Louis The only *edits* I've seen adding spam are from anonymous users. A real user spamming their own question would surely be futile. I was just covering all bases really.

Comment: @Louis - oh yes, that's a thing. What makes it worse is that it's usually done by suggested edit and it sometimes gets approved.

Comment: @ChrisF Ah well... so should we flag with a spam flag in that case? The person whose post it is is going to be caught in the "cross fire" (so to speak). On the other hand, there should be official action taken against the spammer.

Comment: @Louis there was an incident in the past where a real user edited questions to add an affiliate ID to already existing links.  It's a tangental case, but it has happened.

Comment: Don't edits of a post that's on hold always need a peer review? How do these spam edits get through? Bad reviewers?

Comment: @SubliemeSiem Exactly.

Comment: @SubliemeSiem: I'm pretty sure the same rules apply as to other questions (<2k users make suggestions, >2k edits are applied directly).  Only locked posts are special.